# Retrieving Android List Row data when clicked on button in a layout not in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a LinearLayout with ListView and a button with vertical orientation.
I have list View with list item containing a "EditText".
I have a button in a layout as mentioned above which is below the listview not part of listview.I edited the EditText in list row . When I clicked on save button outside the listView I need to retrieve the content of EditText.I am using CursorAdapter. Is there a way in which I can  try to retrieve the text edited in EditText of Android ListView.
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         for (int i = 0; i <listview.getCount() ; i++) {
             View vListSortOrder;
                    vListSortOrder=listview.getChildAt(i);     
                    try{
                    EditText edit=(EditText)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.share_comment_edit);
                   String temp=edit.getText().toString();

        }
      }
    });
```

You have to create a reference to your listview's particular child, and within a for loop you will be able to the reference to it. Do the save then.

Comment: Super Selva. It solved my problem. Excellent . Thank You very much my friend.

Comment: I implemented a ListView using ArrayAdapter. Each listItem (row) contains EditText.
When I try to Edit the text of EditText I was not able to do that , because whenever the keyboard appears getView() method is called and I am not able to edit the text. 
Can you help me in sorting out this issue. 

Thanks in Advance